# Definition of complete partial order and difference with complete lattice

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

According to [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_lattice), a `complete lattice` is a partially ordered set in which all subsets have both a supremum (join) and an infimum (meet).

Whereas, [the wiki page of `complete partial order`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_partial_order) does not give a clear definition of `complete partial order`.

What is the definition of `complete partial order`?

Additionally, what is the difference between `complete partial order` and `Complete lattice`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page gives the definition. It says that an $\omega$-complete partial order (complete partial order), is one where every increasing chain of order type $\omega$ has a supremum.

Now the difference between a complete partial order and a complete lattice should be clear. One only talks about particular chains; the other one talks about any subset.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way: in a complete lattice you have more supremum relations (one for each subset). While in a partially ordered set you only have supremum of subsets of a chain (in a cahin all elements are comparable).